# Print filenames & line number with number of fields greater than 'x'

Tags: awk, sed

I am running Ubuntu Linux. I am in need to print filenames & line numbers containing more than 7 columns. There are several hundred thousand files.

I am able to print the number of columns per file using awk. However the output I am after is something like

`file1.csv-463` which is to suggest file1.csv has more than 7 records on line 463. I am using awk command `awk -F"," '{print NF}' *` to print the number of fields across all files.

Please could I request help?

Comment: `line numbers containing more than 7 records`: Do you mean `line numbers containing more than 7 columns` ?

Comment: yes sorry, 7 columns

Comment: Are `,` inside your files always separator or they might be part of field for example `"this,is,one,field"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNU `awk` with you, try following code then. This will simply check condition if `NF` is greater than `7` then it will print that particular file's file name along with line number and `nextfile` will take program to next Input_file which will save our time because we need not to read whole Input_file then.

```
awk -F',' 'NF>7{print FILENAME,FNR;nextfile}' *.csv
```

Above will print only very first match of condition to get/print all matched lines try following then:

```
awk -F',' 'NF>7{print FILENAME,FNR}' *.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try now. Why is there a `*` after `*.csv` please?

Comment: @usert4jju7, oh sorry that was a typo I have fixed it now.

Comment: If there are too many files for `*.csv` to fit in one command, use `find | xargs awk`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ens 's/\S+/&/8;T;F;=;p' *.csv | paste - - -
```

If there is no eighth column, break.

Output the file name `F`, the line number `=` and print the current line `p`.

Feed the output into a paste command which prints three lines as one.

N.B. The `-s` option resets the line numbers for each file, without it, it will number each line for the entire input.